# UPC API Database Lookup

Tags: android, barcode

I'm writing a commercial app that we anticipate will require about 50,000 UPC look ups per month. For now, I'm just looking for a database that supports UK/USA codes.

I've read a few posts here that keep sending me to [UPC Database](http://upcdatabase.org/). However, this limits searches to only 1000 per day and gives no guarantee of up time.

A lot of the other questions about this subject on SO are a few years old. I was wondering if anyone has any experience with a reliable UPC database? Another one we have looked at is [product open data](http://www.product-open-data.com/) but this didn't have any of the test UPCs we tried.

Has anyone found a UPC database that supports the number of queries we want and is reliable for both UK and USA?

Answer (score 2):

Don't like to answer my own question but came across [Digital Eyes](https://www.digit-eyes.com/cgi-bin/digiteyes/apiDemo.cgi) that has a database of 14 million UPCs and charges $1 per 1000 requests (paid by paypal). They give 500 free lookups to test the system. Seems to have all the UK UPCs I have tested so far

Comment: Try this unlimited and free https://www.erwinmayer.com/