# SYMBOL. ls2208-sr20007r-ur. barcode reader. EAN 128. parenthesis character not read

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode, gs1-128, gs1-ai-syntax

I am trying to use ls2208-sr20007r-ur barcode reader in my project. And my barcodes will be in EAN-128 format. I connect the barcode reader to my comp by USB port, so it becomes a Keyboard emulator. The problem is, when I scan EAN-128 barcode, the parenthesis characters ( and ) are removed from the text.  for example, the code is **(01)125455(15)556545** but it is scanned as **0112545515556545**. But I must use ( and ) characters in my code when scanned any barcode to separate it into parts. I have to take **125455** (for 01) and **556545** (for 15) separately.
   How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: See the extraction part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31760872/2568535