# ZXing Android Embedded GS-1 support

Tags: java, barcode, zxing, code128, gs1-128

## INTRODUCTION

I have a barcode in the Code128C format, which also uses the [GS1-128 specification](https://www.gs1-128.info/).

I use the [ZXing Android Embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) library in my app

Original [Barcode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeNcJ.jpg)

## PROBLEM

When I'm trying to read the barcode, I get **30925018**, but actual data is **(30)925018** - *Count of items: 925018*.

## CODE

```
binding.zxingBarcodeScanner.decodeSingle(new BarcodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
            parseBarcodeResult(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {

        }
    });
```

## ATTEMPTS

1. `DecodeHintType.ASSUME_GS1`

I tried to use `IntentIntegrator` with custom `Intent`

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new 
IntentIntegrator(integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
integrator.setCameraId(0);
integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
Intent intent = integrator.createIntent();
intent.putExtra("ASSUME_GS1", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Using this code I made `Code128Reader` to set `convertFNC1` as true in the  `decodeRow` method, but I still have a bad barcode image from this data.

2. My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098714/is-a-checksum-required-in-the-code128-barcode-specification) about barcodes with images

## QUESTIONS

1. Is the GS1-128 specification supported in the ZXing library?
2. If not, how can I process GS1-128 in the application?

Comment: According to its github page, ZXing supports Code 128, of which GS1-128 is a subset. Those parentheses are not encoded into a GS1-128 barcode though, they're added when presenting the barcode in human-readable form. It seems to me like you were able to scan all the information, but you're looking for a way to extract the various parts in order to be able to present the barcode in a more human-readable form. For that you may need some sort of parser.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/227