# How to decode EAN128 barcode with zxing barcode scanning library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to read an EAN128 barcode using zxing barcode scanning library. And I am using it in the Xamarin shared project like this…

```
private async void OnButtonForBarcodeReadPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ZXingScannerPage scannerPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
    scannerPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
    {
        scannerPage.IsScanning = false;
        var rawBytes = result.RawBytes;
        var barcodeType = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
        var barcodeText = result.Text;
    };
}
```

The problem is that the **Text** property of the *result* does not contain the special character.

I noticed that the property **RawBytes** of the *result* (which is a byte array) has a byte 102 in correct place for every special character but I can't seem to understand how the rest of the bytes have been calculated.

Here is an example. I generate this EAN128 barcode **(21)500600(11)201201**. I did it with an online barcode generator so I am sure that there is a special character in the right place! When I scan it with zxing the **Text** property of the *result* is "2150060011201201" and the length is exactly 16 chars so there is no special character included. And [this is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh50j.png) of the byte array in the **RawBytes** property. As you can see before every application identifier there is a byte 102. But the rest seem a bit of. And when you add a letter in the barcode then it is more confusing.

Is there a way to get the correct barcode text with the special character from the property **RawBytes** or a way to configure the zxing so the **Text** property contains the special character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the **BarcodeFormat** of the ScanningOptions .

```
var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
{
    PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() {
          ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
    },

    ryHarder = true,
    AssumeGS1 = true,
    AutoRotate = true,

};
```